# Can we send Email from J2ME device? Or can we send data to remote server(or local server) from J2ME device?

Tags: java, email, smtp, java-me, j2mepolish

I want to build an application to send some data to the particular email address. For SMS and MMS, I got success but I am not able to find the way to use SMTP to send an email to the particular address. I found that J2ME does not have this option but today I believe there must me some update which will make this think possible. If so, please share this information.

If we are unable to send an email then is there any alternative to sending data to localhost or to a remote server. If so please share the information(code) to implement it.

Comment: Is j2me still  alive in 2017?

Comment: I am recently working on an embedded project which is using MIDP. I learned J2ME during my graduation but never worked on it not I have to work on this project. And looking for available resources. I have no other choice but have to build this project anyhow.

Comment: You might be looking for JavaMail.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html